# Newbie questions for jitsi api

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack, jitsi

I am a newbie to jitsi.

I have the following problem that I need to solve:

1. I want to stream the video via my web cam pointed over my home car parking.
2. The video stream would be received at my office laptop.
3. As such I want to keep an eye on my parked car at home via my web cam.

Following are my questions now:

I am able to run the [Libjitsi](https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi) sender and receiver ([sample](https://jitsi.org/Projects/LibJitsi)) code for my web cam, on a local network setup.

1. How can I use [ice4j](http://code.google.com/p/ice4j/) to enable streaming across networks as the Jitsi product is able to do.

Moreover I am also interested in knowing how Jitsi video calling works and what components/protocols are involved, so that I can leverage that for my own solution

I have hosted an [openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/) xmpp server of mine to facilitate communication for session management for Libjitsi.

Please reply suitable links, reference etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[java-bells](https://github.com/bejayoharen/java-bells) is a "library" designed to wrap ice4j, libjitsi and smack and even contains a sample for making a connection. Since ice4j and libjitsi are, for all intents and purposes undocumented black-boxes, I created java-bells as a thin wrapper around those libraries to make them a bit easier to use. You could also think of it as a demonstration of how to use those libraries. In other words, you might choose to use java-bells directly as a library or just look at java-bells to see how it works and write your own code. Since trying to figure that out by using the jitsi source alone is an exercise in futility, and I don't know of any other approach, I think this is what you should do.

As for docs about the protocols themselves, I only know of the RFCs and the wikipedia pages.

Comment: I was able to get working everything you had suggested, now I can use the sample code to create communication across two clients over two different machines using 'testcall2' and 'testanswer2'.

Meanwhile since my requirements with Java - bells are little different, so right now I am looking up the code to figure out , How can I make video & audio stream of answerer to be received at caller without caller passing its own video & audio stream to the 'answerer' (i.e client running 'testanswer2'), any reference from your side on 'java-bells' code in this regard would be very helpful.

Comment: I can't give you a tutorial. If you have a specific question about something you tried that didn't work, please feel free to ask it.

Comment: Can anyone answer this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549831/desktop-sharing-using-jitsi