# Desktop Sharing using Jitsi

Tags: c#, webrtc, jitsi, desktop-sharing

Hello There,
            I just started doing research on Jitsi- VideoBridge and I am developing a desktop sharing application( Live streaming Audio & Video) which can run on all the platforms natively using WebRTC. Jitsi is all written in JAVA and can someone share/guide me  C# implementation of Jitsi.  I would also like to know what Frames/sec does jitsi offer for 1080p resolution. Let me know any other info is required.

Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone answer this question. Atleast a start/guide?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand a your question. I think you are asking for a c# implementation of WebRTC. Perhaps you want to look at a question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845459/implementing-webrtc-data-channel-for-windows-applications

Comment: Thank you for the response but I need to use C# implementation of  Libjitsi WebRTC desktop capture. Also capture desktop sound.

Comment: Also, why is Libjitsi documentation links broken?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make sense of your question. Libjitsi is written in Java, so there is no C# implementation. If you are looking to access it from C#, you might have better luck asking a more general question about using Java code inside C# (I don't know how to do that).

Comment: Libjisti is horribly documented which is why I created https://github.com/bejayoharen/java-bells -- so people would have some simple, sample code to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But Java bells has capability of screen sharing?the problem with the libjingle and openwebrtc implementations - they had no way of utilizing a video stream from anything other than the hardware camera. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Still waiting for your reply?

Comment: You can try Jidesha for desktop sharing: https://github.com/jitsi/jidesha